# Why am I getting a 404 error at HostGator or why can I no longer call PHP from within HTML files?

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have a problem related to calling PHP from within HTML files at HostGator. Suddenly, the site was giving a 404 error on my primary page, **INDEX.HTML**. After some troubleshooting, I realized that it was because the **AddHandler** statement in the **.htaccess** file was no longer being recognized. I commented it out by using a "#". Doing this avoided the 404 error for the **INDEX.HTML** page, but the page didn't display anything that was dependent on a call to PHP. This is the commented-out statement in the **.htaccess** file.  The front line support folks were unaware of any change on the servers.

```
#AddHandler application/x-httpd-ea-php74 .php .php7 .phtml .html .htm
```

By the way, my **.htaccess** file is located in the **PUBLIC_HTML** folder.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As it turns out, after 10 days HostGator informed me that they indeed upgraded from PHP-74 to LS-PHP-74 (Lite Speed).  They had not informed their front line support after they made the upgrade.  A different **AddHandler** statement was required in **.htaccess**.
Original Statement:

```
AddHandler application/x-httpd-ea-php74 .php .php7 .phtml .html .htm
```

With LS-PHP-74 the statement has to be modified to:

```
AddHandler application/x-httpd-ea-php74___lsphp .php .php7 .phtml .html .htm
```

That allowed PHP to be called from within HTML files again.

Comment: It is a bit surprised that the backend staff did not inform the front line support such a change.

Comment: I would agree with @KenLee's sentiment - this is a huge oversight on the part of HostGator's support team. If this was my account I would already be looking into moving elsewhere if a company their size cannot be bothered to implement proper change management.

Comment: Moving from Apache to LiteSpeed can result in other significant issues with `.htaccess` configs. (LiteSpeed is often billed as a "drop-in replacement" for Apache; except that it's not.)

Answer (score 0):

Yep. they broke my Angular APP routing last night!, thanks HostGator!.

PD: 4 AM the first RING!. --- Hey what happened, it reads not found?.